# Read Matrix from file, give it to main

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a fairly simple program. It reads a matrix from a file that looks like this

```
4 4

a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
```

and outputs it in the console. The program is working as intended:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int n, m;
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("matrix.txt");
  myfile >> n >> m;
  char mat[n][m];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      myfile >> mat[i][j];
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      cout << mat[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now this program is going to grow a lot, so I want to start using headerfiles and declare the functions external so that my main looks more like

```
int main() {
  readMat();
  printMat();
}
```

My Problem is, I don't really know how to do this right. Where should I declare the matrix so that both functions can "see" it? I can't declare it globally as `char mat[n][m]` because I only know `n` and `m` inside `readMat()`.

Or is my whole design flawed and there is much better way to do this?
I would be grateful for every little tip.

I have not worked with multiple files in c++ yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an array like that, when not just multiple translation units, but multiple functions are involved.

Any function needs to know the exact data types it receives as parameters, and this must be declared at compile time.

Here, you don't know the type of the array until runtime. `array[10]` and `array[15]` are different types. Don't be fooled by the fact their name might be the same. It's not the name that matters, but the type, like `int [10]` or `int [11]`.

You have two basic options:

- Use templates.
- Convert your array to a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Then you can declare the array (now a vector) globally, and/or pass it as a parameter to your multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Matrix.h**

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

namespace mynamespace {

template <class T>
class Matrix {
private:
    int m_rows;
    int m_columns;

    T** m_data;

public:      
    Matrix(); // Default Constructor - Null or Empty Matrix
    Matrix( const int rows, const int columns ); // Empty Matrix With Defined Size
    Matrix( const int rows, const int columns, const T** data ); // Defined Matrix

    T** getData() const;

}; // Matrix

#include "Matrix.inl"

} // mynamespace

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

**Matrix.inl**

```
// Matrix Constructor and Function Implementations Here
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
#include "Matrix.h"
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace mynamespace;

void readMatrix( std::fstream& fin, const std::string& strFilename, Matrix& matrixIn );
void printMatrix( const Matrix& matrix );

int main() {        
    std::fstream fileIn; // Prefer to not use "using namespace std;"
    std::string  strFilename( "Matrix.txt" );

    Matrix<type> mat(); // Default Empty Matrix To Be Filled In

    readMatrix( fileIn, strFilename, mat );
    printMatrix( mat );

    return 0;

} // main

void readMatrix( std::fstream& fin, const std::string& strFilename, Matrix& mat ) {
    // Do Work Here To Populate Matrix Object
} // readMatrix

void printMatrix( Matrix& mat ) {
    // Do Work Here To Print Matrix Being Passed In 
} // printMatrix
```

With this pseudo code, the design here allows any type of matrix to be constructed. The matrix is an object of a template type. The implementation of generating a matrix by reading in data from a file, and the implementation of displaying or printing that matrix are independent of the class itself. This allows for the matrix class to be as generic as possible without having to rely on any other libraries. The functions that do the work are stand alone functions that accept a matrix object. A modification may be needed in your text or binary file to work with this construct.

**matrix.txt**

```
type
4 4

a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
a b c d
```

The only problem with this, is it should already be obvious: you need to define what type of data this matrix will hold when instantiating it. Yet you do not know the type until after you read the file in. So this code does have a bug in it that would need to be address. However, the overall design method used here is to only show how to keep similar code objects contained with in their own class object while separating independent code blocks that does work on them. Now other class objects may have a file reading and print methods, but normally Vector (math & not containers) and Matrix classes usually don't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very enlightning. While I didnt use it (just using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` sufficed for this case), I have saved this as a template for later use.